# Inner Exception given during sending email Via C#, Port 25 has no Process running

Tags: c#, visual-studio, email, smtp, protocols

I am trying to send emails through `C#.NET code` but giving Inner-Exceptions:

`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`

The code to send emails is, kindly inform what am i wrong with (the code will run in a local domain under our own Network):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("email1@yahoo.com","email2@gmail.com"); 
smtpClient client = new SmtpClient(); 
client.Port = 25; 
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
client.Host = "SecretIP of SMPT Server OR IP"; 
mail.Subject = "This is a test email."; 
mail.Body = "This is my test email body"; 
bool mailSent = false; 
bool serverListening = false; 

try 
{ 
    Ping p = new Ping(); 
    PingReply pr = p.Send(client.Host, 5000); 
    if(pr.Status == IPStatus.Success) 
    { 
        serverListening = !(serverListening); 
        client.Send(email); 
        emailSent = !(emailSent); 
    } 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Exception ex2 = ex;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    while (ex2 != null)
    {
        errorMessage += ex2.ToString();
        ex2 = ex2.InnerException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**STEP # 1:**

First of all, ping your `email server's` IP/Alias-Name from  `cmd.exe`

In your case IP of email-server is `SecretIP of SMPT Server OR IP`
( i.e. the value of `client.Host` )

So your command will be:

```
ping IP
//OR
ping Alias Name
```

---

**STEP # 2:**

Now that you have confirmed wether the IP is being pinged successfully or not follow the below instructions:

- If server IP is not being pinged then you should consult your internal IT Department Team and ask about the server IP on which `Microsoft Exchange Server` is installed.
- If server IP is being pinged successfully then it means that the IP you are pinging is accessible but

  - the Microsoft Server Exchange Server is not installed on the server/host and that is being used by you in the `client.Host` line
  - As Microsoft Exchange Server is not installed on this IP the reason being of mail-failure.
  - Ask the IT Department for the correct IP OR if you have an email configured in Outlook for your own domain then goto Outlook - File - Info - Account Settings - E-mail TAB.... double click it and copy the Alias Name. This Alias name is the server having your EMAILS and does a lot of processing with your emails :-)

---

**HELPING NOTE:**

Visit [Microsoft Exchange Server Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) to learn more about it.

Comment: Yes, it was the wrong Alias Name i was giving. I gave the same alias name that was used under MS Outlook => File - Info - Account Settings - E-mail ..... TAB. Double clicked it and got the Alias name of LOCAL EMAIL SERVER. and used that HOST in my code and the emails started working Thanks